# Openssl & RSA : how many public exponents are possible?

Tags: rsa, openssl

I would like to know if it is possible to set the public exponent we want with *"OpenSSL RSA"* or if it is really limited to 2 possible exponents:

- 3
- 65537

If yes, why ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The public exponent of a RSA key is, nominally, an odd integer $e \geq 3$. Any such integer can be used with RSA, although not necessarily with any modulus $n$: $n$ and $e$ must be such that $e$ and $\phi(n)$ are relatively prime to each other. This is why $e$ cannot be even: $\phi(n)$ is even, so it can never be prime to another even number. Apart from that, any odd integer can be theoretically encountered as a public exponent (not $1$, but some implementations will accept it nonetheless, although it is very weak).

A specific implementation of RSA may be more restrictive. [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/) appears to have, by default, the following limitations:

- The modulus $n$ must not be larger than 16384 bits.
- The public exponent $e$ must not be greater than $n$.
- If $n$ is larger than 3072 bits, then $e$ must fit in 64 bits.

These conditions (especially the third) are fairly arbitrary, but so it is. In fact, you want to be even more restrictive, because of interoperability. For instance, the default RSA implementation in Windows (CryptoAPI) cannot process RSA public keys where the public exponent does not fit on 32 bits.

There is no known security advantage to large public exponents over small public exponents. However, there is a quite plain *performance* advantage to using small exponents, and the smaller the better. Which us why $e = 3$ should be preferred. Using $e = 65537$ is a well-entrenched tradition, for no real good reason (even with $e = 65537$, RSA public-key operations are still quite fast, so it does not matter much in practice).

---

"65537" was selected for several reasons:

- Its binary representation contains mostly zeros, which gives a small performance advantage in a [square-and-multiply](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) algorithm (you still need to do 16 squarings, but only one non-squaring multiplication).
- It is prime, which is good for some key generation algorithms: for a RSA key, you need to generate two big primes $p$ and $q$, such that $e$ is relatively prime to $p-1$ and $q-1$. By choosing $e = 65537$, you can generate $p$ and $q$ without caring about $e$, and just start over if the "relatively prime" condition turns out not to be fulfilled (happens with probability $1/65537$ for each prime, so quite rarely).
- It is bigger than $3$, which appeases people.

None of these reasons is really strong. Public-key operations in RSA are fast anyway; and $e = 3$ is the fastest you can get. If you really need ultimate performance for public-key operations, then $e = 65537$, while being about the best 17-bit exponent you can find, is still substantially slower than RSA with $e=3$. Not that it really matters most of the time (*private*-key operations are where performance issues usually are; and if you really need the extra cycles for public-key operations then you should use [Rabin signatures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin_signature_algorithm), not RSA).

Prime generation can take into account the public exponent, e.g. you can generate candidate $p$ values as $p = 3r+2$ where $r$ is an odd random integer; this ensures that $p$ will not be a multiple of $3$ and that $p-1$ will be relatively prime to $3$ too. This process can be extended to ensure that not only $p-1$ will be relatively prime to your pulbic exponent of choice, but also that the candidate $p$ will not be a multiple of 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13... which will make bad candidate pruning faster.

The qualms some people have about $e = 3$ are the consequences of an old piece information that got corrupted along the way and turned into a myth. See [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2335/should-rsa-public-exponent-be-only-in-3-5-17-257-or-65537-due-to-security-c/2339#2339) for details.

Comment: Aren't there a few very rather remote attacks on e = 3?

Comment: To add what might be the source of the question: the older *commandline utility* `openssl genrsa` only supports 3 and F4=65537. The newer (since 1.0.0 in 2010) and less known commandline `genpkey`, or custom code calling the *library*, can have the broader range described here.

Comment: @owlstead: if you use RSA without a proper padding procedure, then it is malleable, and this is easier to exploit if $e$ is small. However, the issue there is not a small $e$, but lack of proper padding.

Answer (score 2):

No; you can theoretically use (almost) any $e$ such that $1 < e < \varphi(n)$.
There are some potential attacks on RSA with low exponents — see [this
question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/8454/what-security-authorities-and-standards-reject-e-3-in-rsa-when-and-with-what)
by fgrieu — so we tend to prefer larger exponents.

As for why 65537 is an extremely common exponent: it has a lot of benefits while
still being large. See [this answer by
fgrieu](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/3113/2454) for more information. To
summarize, 65537 is essentially a compromise between large exponents and
efficiency.

To be more precise about which $e$ you can use, the only condition on $e$ is
that you must be able to find a $d$ such that $ed \equiv 1 \pmod{\lambda(n)}$,
i.e. that a multiplicative modular inverse must exist. This is only the case if
$\operatorname{gcd}(e, \lambda(n))=1$. Now, it's well-known in number theory
that $\lambda(x) \mid \varphi(x)$ for all $x$, so if we choose an $e$ such that
$\operatorname{gcd}(e, \lambda(n)) \ne 1$, then we will have
$\operatorname{gcd}(e, \varphi(n)) \ne 1$ as well.  But

$$\varphi(n) = \varphi(pq) = \varphi(p)\varphi(q) = (p-1)(q-1),$$

so we would have that $\operatorname{gcd}(e, p-1) \ne 1$ *or*
$\operatorname{gcd}(e, q-1) \ne 1$. So, you cannot use an $e$ that shares a
factor with $p-1$ or $q-1$, but other than that, all of them are fair game.

Comment: There are no security benefits to large exponents (assuming you use RSA properly, including proper padding and so forth; and if you don't use RSA properly, then you've got bigger problems and might be in trouble no matter what exponent you use).

Answer (score -4):

I am very unsure why there is so much push to use small exponents. A lot of people is stating that 65537 is large, how it is large? It is small, in fact EXTREMELY small. A lot of people is stating that there are more important security concerns than small exponents, while it might be true I don't see how it should convince me to use small exponent? More, a lot of libraries arbitraly limits the size of exponent without a reason. Is it ok? I think it is not. Windows can't process? Bad for windows then. Anyone else? I want big exponents, taht's it. I am not a mathematician, but as far as I understand how RSA works, big exponent is much safer and it protects from other security vulnerabilities. So it is bad? Why people try to convince to use small exponents? Why US is restrticting usage of bigger RSA keys? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Export_of_cryptography_from_the_United_States ? Can someone explain? What, bigger exponents they can't crack, yes? Good to know!

RSA is generating keys from three numbers `p,q,e` where `e` ends up directly as an exponent in one of these keys, usually public, because we can controll this exponent by putting the mentioned 65537 there.

If we set up this exponent to some const value eg. 65537, then the only parts than attacker needs to guess is the `p` and `q`, if we know the length of the key we can assume a range of primes that can be used. Then we can do brute force attack using all the combinations for the range of these primes to guess them, we validate by encoding something with public key and trying to decode by the private key generated by our attack. I think knowig e upfront makes the task much easier, because there is much smaller search space. That's why I want big exponent.

Comment: "If we set up this exponent to some const value, then the only parts than attacker needs to guess", actually,  tell put $e$ in the public key, so the attacker never needs to guess it.   "we can do brute force attack using all the combinations for the range of these primes to guess them" - brute forcing 1024 bit primes is *laughably* beyond feasible...

Comment: Yeah, as Bill Gates said in the past: "640K ought to be enough for anybody". And e don't need to end up in public key, it can be kept in private!!! It is put into public only because we can set its value upfornt of the algorithm.

Comment: Sigh..., $e$ is in the public key because the person with the public key needs it to do anything with the public key (be it public key encryption or signature verification).  If the public key only consists of $n$, what do you expect someone to be able to do with it?

Comment: We can generate the keys so that the input variable e is never exposed in the public key.

Comment: @Krzysztof Cichocki: in every [article](https://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/Rsapaper.pdf) or [standard](https://pkcs1.grieu.fr) about RSA that I know, $e$ is the public exponent, is part of the public key (or implicitly known), and in every case is public. If it was not, verifying a signature or encrypting would require knowledge of non-public information (against the goals of public-key cryptography), since both operations require to compute $x^e\bmod n$. As to the rationale of large $e$, I suggest [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/8454/555).

Comment: RSA generates two keys from three primes p,q,e. In one of the keys e is directly used as exponent, but this key don't need to be public. Keys can be swapped, so we never expose our initial e in the publickey. You've got it?

Comment: @Krzysztof Cichocki: Yes, if you generate an RSA key from $p$, $q$, $e$ then "swap keys", said integer $e$ must be secret, and must be large, much larger than enough to be unguessable (per [this](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-48910-X_1) famous attack). But then said integer no longer is a "public exponent", which is what the question is about (see title). It becomes known as "private exponent", and gets noted $d$. Relatively minor nitpick: neither $e$ nor $d$ needs to be prime, and they are best designated as _exponents_ rather than _keys_.