# Why is a smaller value preferred for the public key in RSA?

Tags: rsa, public-key, keys

For my practice implementation of the RSA cryptosystem I use a random value generation function such the value of public key *e* holds:

- The public exponent $e$ and the modulus $n$ should be $e<\phi(n)$
- $e$ and  $\phi(n)$ are coprime, $gcd(e,\phi(n)) = 1$

Although this works satisfactorily, the algorithm returns values of $e$ which are very large in magnitude which, apparently, is undesirable.

**Why is it preferred to generate smaller values for the public exponent in the RSA system?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said, choosing a large $e$ can make you vulnerable to attacks such as [Wiener attack's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener%27s_attack) because a big $e$ makes it possible to have a small $d$. It will also make the cost of your encryption higher. So big $e$ is not necessarily a problem (if make some verification on $d$, such as $d>\frac{1}{3}\times n^{\frac{1}{4}}$), but not the best choice.

A very common value for the public exponent is  $e=65537$, because $65537 = 2^{16}+1$, which has a nice binary representation (like all [Fermat primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number)):
$$10000000000000001$$
This allow a fast computation using algorithm such as the [sliding windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring#Sliding_window_method)

You could choose $e=3$ for more efficiency, but you have to use a proper padding (RSA OAEP for instance). **Using $e=3$ without proper padding will weaker your encryption scheme.**

More details can be found in [fgrieu's answer to a similar question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3110/impacts-of-not-using-rsa-exponent-of-65537).

Comment: Big e is necessary for small(ish) d, but not sufficient. People who (stupidly) want small d (overwhelmingly) get big e, but simply choosing big e randomly or arbitrarily has negligible probability of giving small d.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 You're right, I have edited my answer accordigly

Answer (score 2):

Cheaper encryption in terms of computational resources and time.